# Querystring without values

Tags: java, jsp

Im new to `JSP` and I am using a flag in my application like the URL below:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/result.jsp?params
```

How do I get that flag in the landing page?

Comment: There isn't even a question mark.

Comment: even without values, there supposed to be `=` symbol at the end, I guess

Comment: It should be using .htaccess Apache ReWrite Module to Rewrite Your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `request.getQueryString()` to access the raw query string (everything after the `?` up to the first `#`, if there was one) as it was in the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames();

while (en.hasMoreElements()) {

    String paramName = (String) en.nextElement();
    if (paramName.equals("params")) {

       ....
    }

}
```

If you do like this you don't have to specify a value for the parameter.

You can check this [example](http://www.javadb.com/get-request-parameters-in-a-servlet/)

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("params")` will return you a blank-string.

To set a `boolean` flag, you can simply do.

```
boolean flag = request.getParamater("params") != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **result.jsp** file, you can get the param value within the scriplet tag **<%...%>** like this :

```
<%
String params = request.getParameter("params");
%>
```

Also, as DnR quoted in the comments, you will have to place '=' after the param flag even if you don't want to associate a value with this flag.